# IndexedDB undefined in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, indexeddb

We are developers of a healthcare app that makes use of IndexedDB. The IE11 installation at one of our customer companies is showing window.indexedDB and window.msIndexedDB to be undefined, meaning our app will not work. We've not had this on any of our other customers.

We had a screenshare meeting with the customer and I was able to determine the following things:

1. They are on Windows 10
2. The Document mode in the dev tools Emulation tab is correctly set to 11. Confirmed in Console by checking document.documentMode returning 11
3. The Browser Profile is correctly set to Desktop
4. The only Group Policies in Computer Configuration -> Administrative Template -> Windows Components -> Internet Explorer -> Internet Control Panel -> General Page -> Browsing History, are defaults and shouldn't affect it.

Are there anything else we can ask our customer's IT department to check as to why IndexedDB would still be undefined?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you to check following things:

1. If they run a local file rather than an HTTP resource, IE will restrict access to the API from file (or non-HTTP) origins. You can refer to [the accepted answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510035/how-to-get-indexeddb-to-work-in-ie11).
2. Is the first line in your webpage  `<!doctype HTML>`? You can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703520/why-does-internet-explorer-11-not-detect-indexeddb).
3. If you tried everything and none of them works, you can try to reset the IE settings to the defaults.

Comment: This is over HTTPS, and we've tried resetting settings back to defaults for the doctype, yes we have <!doctype html> at first character position of the file as well as <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">.

Comment: What is the IE11 version of the customer?

Comment: 11.1746.15063.0CO

Comment: It is the older version of IE11. My suggestion is let your customer install the latest update and try it again.